# How to merge 2 YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube

I have 2 channels with the same first and last name. I own both of them. I want to put all my subscribers and videos together. Any idea how I can do this or request this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually merge YouTube Channels [according to Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846).

They do point out:

> However, you can [download your videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/answer.py?answer=56100) from your own channel. Once you've downloaded your video, you can re-upload it to a different channel. View count and other statistics will start over for the new upload.